# Getting an error when i try to access a nested route in react-router

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

Hi im getting an error:

```
 [react-router] Location "/setup/gender" did not match any routes
```

I am able to access /setup and everything works fine.
Here is the react-router code:

```
ReactDOM.render(

  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Root}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path ="/setup">
        <IndexRoute component={Setup} />
        <Route path="/gender" component={Gender}></Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and within my setup component :

```
export default class Setup extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to="/setup/gender">gender</Link>
        <SetupNav />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Use <Link to="/gender">gender</Link> instead of what u are using. Solved my problem last time i ran into such an issue

Answer (score 0):

```
<Route path="/gender" component={Gender}></Route>
```

should become

```
<Route path="/setup/gender" component={Gender}></Route>
```

Comment: Im getting an error when i try to do that. Im not getting the SetupNavbar, I want to make several other routes that would have this navbar.               Also when I tried it this way my assets arent loading properly I am getting a 304 error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yikes, thought it was an easy fix but saw you're handling routes a bit differently than we do. Not too sure what's up, unfortunately